# python array element prefixed with 'u'

Tags: python

I have a function using popen() that returns stdout as an array.

using Python3 the arrays are returned correctly, but under python 2.7 each element is prefixed with a 'u'

```
def exe(cmd):
    from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
    p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, close_fds=True)
    arr = p.stdout.read().decode().split("\n")
    print(arr)
    del arr[-1]
    if(arr[0]=='not found.'): arr = [];
    return arr
```

[u'10-000801d5a12d', u'']

Where is this 'u' coming from and how do I prevent it ?

Comment: You don't prevent it. When you print the list you get the representation of the content, not the value.

Comment: Only partially tongue-in-cheek answer - prevent it by switching Python 3.x! As far as I am aware, the worst thing about pre-3.x Python was strings' unicode support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `u` indicates the string is a Unicode string. This means that the string has been decoded from an encoding, such as UTF-8 or ISO-8895-1, into a unambiguous type. If you `print arr[0]` it will be encoded back to your terminal without the `u`.

This would have happened during the `.read().decode()`. You should really pass the proper file encoding to decode otherwise a system one could be used which may not be appropriate. If your file contains just ASCII chars then you won't see a problem.

The reason why it's different is because in Python 3, normal strings (decoded) are always Unicode strings whereas byte strings (from `.read()`) are a special type.

If you really don't want the `u`, remove the `.decode()` method but you really don't need to.

Answer (score 1):

The `u` stands for unicode to indicate it is a unicode string when printed. It doesn't affect the array contents in any way and is merely an indication

Answer (score 1):

`u'10-000801d5a12d'` means '10-000801d5a12d' is a `unicode` string.

You can see it [here](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#introduction-to-unicode) at python docs

Use:

```
str(myString)
```

You can also use `encode` if you need specific encoding:

```
"myString".encode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

The `u` means the string is a unicode string.
If you really want a python `str`, you can cast it like that:

```
str(my_var)
```